# Perform casting from string to key

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, encryption, cryptography

I have create a secrete key and need to store it in database, so i convert it into string, after that I want to get back these key from database so what was possible way to find this?

```
KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("RC4");
SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");  
String mainKey=secretKey.toString();
String cipherkey=cipher.toString());
```

Comment: you could store it without converting to string

Comment: You should not save you in string format, it isn't safe either.

Comment: MyDog how can save without using datatype?? if i save without converting what will be the datatype of column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store secretkey after converting it to bytes  and make use of BLOB datatype  in Database

```
  SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
    byte[] secretKeyBytes=secretKey.getEncoded();
```

again to convert it into secret key use this

```
SecretKey secretKey= new SecretKeySpec(secretKeyBytes, 0, secretKeyBytes.length, "RC4");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion to string is almost certainly wrong. No standard key classes override `toString()`, so your output will not be the key data.

To convert your key to a string, use `getEncoded()` to obtain the key bytes and then decide upon a way to represent these as text. A common choice may be to hex-encode them (see `DatatypeConverter` class).

To restore from a string, first convert it back to a byte array (e.g. hex-decode). Then, you can recreate your key with:

```
SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "RC4");
```

Don't try to store a `Cipher` object as you attempt to do in your sample code. This makes no sense.

Comment: Dear Duncan please send me valid code for RC4 encryption and decryption

Comment: @LokeshKumar Sorry, I'm not a free coding service. I've tried to answer your question as you originally presented it. If you Google, you'll find plenty of examples out there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following, this is available with *KeyGenerator* class :

```
char[] key = encodeHex(aesKey.getEncoded());
```

or

```
byte[] key  = aesKey.getEncoded();
```

Happy to help.

Comment: Hi Lokesh, if answer is useful then use upwards arrow to vote it up, otherwise if your problem is not yet solve, then let me know the issue.